# Equals method returning always true JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, equals, hashcode

I am having a problem with overriding equals method in one class, this class has only one attribute which is a 2-dimensional array called grid. This is the constructor:

```
public World(int n, int m){
    this.grid = new Object[n][m];
}
```

The equals method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (null == obj)
        return false;
    if ( !obj instanceof World)
        return false;
    World other = (World) obj;
    if ( !Arrays.deepEquals(grid, other.grid))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I have already overridden the `hashCode()` method as well, but the problem is that doesn't matter the case, the equals is always returning true. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: actually it is always returning false

Comment: Are you sure the objects in the grid are equal?

Comment: Are you sure that `Arrays.deepEquals(grid, other.grid)` returns what you expect it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful - you're messing with `Object` here.

Regardless of the actual objects you place into that array, they will all be using `Object#equals` for its comparison.  The reason for that [lies in the documentation of `Arrays#deepEquals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)).

> Two possibly null elements e1 and e2 are deeply equal if any of the following conditions hold:
>
> - e1 and e2 are both arrays of object reference types, and Arrays.deepEquals(e1, e2) would return true
> - e1 and e2 are arrays of the same primitive type, and the appropriate overloading of Arrays.equals(e1, e2) would return true.
> - e1 == e2
> - e1.equals(e2) would return true.

And...guess what `Object#equals` does:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Your arrays will only *ever* be equivalent if and only if they contain the ***exact same instances*** of stuff between them.

Applying stricter types around your array, such as a concrete class, may help you to get around the issue.  We don't know what you're storing in that array, so I can't suggest anything concrete, but look to move away from `Object`.

Comment: If `Object#equals` is overridden, the overriding method will be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof World)) {
        return false;
    } 
    World other = (World) obj;
    if (!Arrays.deepEquals(this.grid, other.grid))
        return false;      
    return true;
}
```